# Programmatically add an object of web user control into another user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, webusercontrol

i have a web form in to which i load a web user control(A)

an when a button on control A is clicked it loads an array of another web user control named as `infobox`

when i add the user control  in to control collection of web user control A it does not show.

below is the code: on button click of control A

```
foreach (Categories category in CategoriesDataList)
            {
                InfoBox ib = new InfoBox();
                ib.LiteralName = category.Category_Name;
                span_tempList.Controls.Add(ib);
                ib = null;           
            }   



span_tempList is a `<span>` tag with `runat=server`
```

below i HTML and cs Code for InfoBox Control

```
 public partial class InfoBox : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label ltrlName = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public InfoBox()
        {

        }

        public string LiteralName
        {
            get { return ltrlName.Text; }
            set { ltrlName.Text = value; }
        }

    }
```

--HTML--

```
<div style="width:10%;float:left;">
        <asp:Label ID="ltrlName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div style="width:20%;float:left;">
        <asp:Image ID="imgPicture" runat="server" ImageUrl="" />
    </div>
    <div style="width:70%;float:right;">

    </div>
```

also tried to add controls to page doesn't works

Comment: Have you checked to see if the IsPostBack property of the page in the Page constructor true or false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not create an instance of a UserControl via constructor but by using [LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.loadcontrol.aspx) if you want to add it to the page's control-collection.

```
InfoBox ib = (InfoBox)LoadControl("InfoBox.ascx");
```

Also, why are you setting the control to `null`? It will be disposed automatically at the end of the page-lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks For the help. it helped me and was able to load control programatically.. thanks but `"InfoBox.ascx.cs"` gave me error it was only `.ascx` file path `LoadControl` was asking for.